# SQL error MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have altered a table in my MySQL Database. I am getting this error. I have no idea how to work around to change the syntax if that is the error.

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `invoicedb`.`c_order` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `first_name` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `phone_number` `last_name` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `emailID` `email` CHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `address` `phone_number` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT 0000000000 ,
CHANGE COLUMN `productID` `address_l1` CHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `invoiceNo` `address_l2` CHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `total` `product` INT(6) NULL DEFAULT Bicycle ,
ADD COLUMN `chassis_number` CHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `prouct`,
ADD COLUMN `invoice_number` CHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `chassis_number`,
ADD COLUMN `invoice_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT 'DD/MM/YYYY' AFTER `invoice_number`,
ADD COLUMN `valid_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT 'DD/MM/YYYY' AFTER `invoice_date`,
ADD COLUMN `invoice_value` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT 0000.00 AFTER `valid_date`;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Bicycle ,
ADD COLUMN `chassis_number` CHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `product`' at line 8
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `invoicedb`.`c_order` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `first_name` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `phone_number` `last_name` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `emailID` `email` CHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `address` `phone_number` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT 0000000000 ,
CHANGE COLUMN `productID` `address_l1` CHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `invoiceNo` `address_l2` CHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `total` `product` INT(6) NULL DEFAULT Bicycle ,
ADD COLUMN `chassis_number` CHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `product`,
ADD COLUMN `invoice_number` CHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `chassis_number`,
ADD COLUMN `invoice_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT 'DD/MM/YYYY' AFTER `invoice_number`,
ADD COLUMN `valid_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT 'DD/MM/YYYY' AFTER `invoice_date`,
ADD COLUMN `invoice_value` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT 0000.00 AFTER `valid_date`
```

Comment: Bicycle is a text, but field has been defined as INT(6)

Comment: Also does this refer to a typo `AFTER \`prouct\`,`

Answer (score 0):

Bicycle is string and needs quotes, so column needs to have **varchar**, **char** or **text** type:

```
CHANGE COLUMN `total` `product` varchar(40) NULL DEFAULT 'Bicycle' ,
```